# Why does not source local images?

Tags: html, css

This syntax is incorrect?

**CODE CSS:**

```
.navbar-custom{
    background:url(images/bgi/bg.png);
}
```

**CODE HTML**

```
    <nav class="navbar navbar-custom">
       //some code HTML
    </nav>
```

I put an image to view image made way

[image]

Do you know where does this matter?

**EDIT:**

[image]

Comment: this looks valid to me - could you please point out what your problem is?

Comment: Where are your CSS and HTML files located? Are they in the test directory?

Comment: Is you `CSS` or `HTML` file is in **test** folder?

Comment: Yes, look at the picture above

Comment: I think you need to add some CSS describing the size of <nav>. Try adding width/hight/float.

Comment: I tried another image and still does not work ... it does not appear in Google Chrome cut

Comment: Open your developer tools/element inspector and look at the network tab. It'll tell you whether your image was loaded correctly and if not why not.

Answer (score 5):

Is your css file in the "test" folder? The path you provide in url is relative to wherever the css file is saved.

You also have no quotes around your path, which should be there - but I'm not sure would cause the issue.

Try:

```
.navbar-custom{
    background: url("/images/bgi/bg.png");
}
```

With the forward slash, you're going back to the root of the site - and then into the images folder. This would solve the problem if for example you have css in a sub-folder of test. I've also added in the quotes for completeness.

Answer (score 4):

The syntax is correct. The URL is not.

URLs in stylesheets are relative to the *stylesheet* URL, not the HTML document URL.

The `images` directory is a sibling to the `css` directory. It isn't inside it.

```
background:url(../images/bgi/bg.png);
```